# Explaination on phasor diagram for RL circuit?

Tags: inductor, phase-shift, phasor

[image]

This is the phasor diagram which I had drawn from the value of phase difference(deg) from MULTISIM. I'm a bit confuse here... shouldn't by theory, when inductance is increase, thus the degree for Vl also gets bigger? But from the data from MULTISIM, it shows the opposite.

Comment: Show us your schematic and explain exactly how you are measuring the phase angles.

Comment: In addition to schematic, please specify the frequency you are using for the measurement.

Answer (score 3):

> *shouldn't by theory, when inductance is increase, thus the degree for*
> `Vl` *also gets bigger?*

For `Vl` read \$V_L\$.

No, think about what happens when \$R\$ gets smaller and smaller until it eventually equals zero ohms. At that point, the voltage across the inductor (\$V_L\$) equals \$V_S\$ i.e. the angle gets smaller until it equals 0° relative to \$V_S\$.

This can also be seen in the angle of the current. As \$R\$ gets smaller, the current becomes lagging more and more and, when \$R\$ is zero ohms, the current in the series circuit is lagging by 90° and, of course this means that the voltage is leading current by 90° and is at 0° relative to the supply voltage.

If you'd used better quality numbers or better quality calculations you'd find that the two angles shown in each diagram add-up to exactly 90°. Your first diagram appears to be in error in that respect.